# What is the default GUI sftp application in Debian?

Tags: debian, software-installation, sftp

I found only the following in `apt-get`, but nothing seems to be relevant, then much pure `ftp` clients. 
I think sftp is the same as SSH ftp, so `scp` should do the case, but I would like to have a GUI. 
I just want to move files to my raspberry pies in local network.

```
apt-cache search sftp | grep sftp
gesftpserver - sftp server submodule for OpenSSH
libnet-sftp-foreign-perl - client for the Secure File Transfer Protocol
libnet-sftp-sftpserver-perl - Secure File Transfer Protocol Server
openssh-sftp-server - secure shell (SSH) sftp server module, for SFTP access from remote machines
python-fs-plugin-sftp - Python filesystem abstraction - SFTP access
rssh - Restricted shell allowing scp, sftp, cvs, svn, rsync or rdist
ruby-net-sftp - Ruby implementation of the SFTP protocol
sftpcloudfs - SFTP interface to Rackspace/OpenStack storage services
vsftpd - lightweight, efficient FTP server written for security
vsftpd-dbg - lightweight, efficient FTP server written for security (debug)
```

OS: Debian 8.7

Comment: Your file browser, with gvfs.

Comment: @muru How to access its GUI?

Comment: Depends. Find your browsers address bar and go to `sftp://host` (or `sftp://user@host`). If you're using Nautilus/Nemo, press Ctrl-L. For Thunar, I think the same shortcut applies.

Comment: @muru Yes, I can read those files in Firefox. However, I cannot cp there any files.

Comment: Not in Firefox. Your *file* browser (Nautilus, Thunar, Dolphin, etc.).

Comment: @muru Works! Of course. Feel free to add it as an answer.

Comment: Not really an answer, but also consider using the fish protocol, which only requires that the server have SSH installed. It can also be accessed from most Linux file browsers, eg. `fish://user@host/path/to/file.txt`

Comment: @Octopus Can you please explain the benefits of `fish` as an answer more thoroughly?

Comment: fixed grammer etc. However don't know meaning of “, then much pure ftp clients.” so left alone.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In most modern DEs, the file browser/manager (Nautilus, Nemo, Thunar, Dolphin, etc.) should support SFTP (using GVFS in the case of Nautilus, Nemo, etc., and probably some KDE library for Dolphin). So, use your file browser's address bar (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>L</kbd> in Nautilus, Nemo and Thunar, iirc) and go to `sftp://host` or `sftp://user@host` . Any address usable by SSH would work here, and entries in your SSH config file are available.

Comment: Assume you store there password and username. Can they add appropriate changes in `$HOME/.ssh/...`? - - I am just thinking how these GUIs are working.

Comment: @LéoLéopoldHertz준영 no, I don't think your SSH configuration is modified. Best guess, they use a keyring, if available, to store the password. Not sure, though.

Answer (score 3):

`gftp` supports SFTP. It has a GTK interface. I don't think there is a *default* client though.

Comment: `apt-cache search gftp` gives nothing. What is the name of the interface?

Comment: https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=gftp should help.

Comment: I find nothing there for Debian 8.7.

Comment: Yes, my bad. You can try Dolphin instead, and you should have that on Jessie.

Answer (score 2):

Debian with Gnome shell?

I'd say Nautilus. I only have Debian 9 on my machine so steps might differ a little bit.

1. You go to "Other locations" in the bottom left panel of Nautilus
2. Click the input at the right of the label "Connect to server" in the bottom center of the window.
3. Write the following (replace the ip with your server's ip or hostname):

   > sftp://192.168.1.100
4. Press enter, a popup window will appear prompting for credentials.
5. Complete user and password credentials and press enter.

That should do it.
This way you can even save the connection for future use.

Answer (score 2):

i do not think there is a real default. [filezilla](https://packages.debian.org/wheezy/filezilla) is another option.